# SQL how to retrieve latest result from each joined table

Tags: sql, database, join, mariadb, greatest-n-per-group

I would like to retrieve one large table of products with the latest rows from all the joined tables via with MAX(ID) of each group (productToken) which ich unique name of the product. Joined tables are - products (store), availability (status), description (products), and price of the product. All of them contains the unique productToken and the mentioned tables can be changed over time by adding a new record (independently) so my aim is to compose one big table (with actual info about the products) via retrieving the lastest record from each table. My code is this. First added product worked well, but things got strange after adding new records to any of the tables (query has retrieved no results).

```
SELECT *
FROM products
JOIN productsStore ON products.productToken = productStore.productToken
JOIN productsStatus ON products.productToken = productsStatus.productToken
JOIN productsPrice ON products.produstToken = productsPrice.productToken
JOIN categories ON products.categoryToken = categories.categoryToken
WHERE products.shopToken = '$shopToken' 
    AND products.productID IN 
        (SELECT MAX(productID) 
        FROM products 
        GROUP BY productToken)
    AND productsPrice.productPriceID IN 
        (SELECT MAX(productPriceID) 
        FROM productsPrice
        GROUP BY produktToken)
    AND productsStatus.productStatusID IN 
        (SELECT MAX(productStatusID) 
        FROM productsStatus
        GROUP BY productToken)
    AND produktyStore.productStoreID IN 
        (SELECT MAX(productStoreID) 
        FROM productsStore
        GROUP BY productToken)
    AND categories.categoryID IN 
        (SELECT MAX(categoryID) 
        FROM categories
        GROUP BY categoryToken)
ORDER BY categories.categoryID DESC
```

Comment: update your question add  a proper data sample and the expected  result

Comment: Which version of MySQL are you running?

Comment: @Rudi: you latest edit made the original query absolutly unreadable. I rolled it back. Feel free to proceed again, but do not remove the query, otherwise your question becomes impossible to understand and answer.

Comment: @GMB it is actually 10.3.21-MariaDB

Comment: @Rudi: ok - so the second query in my answer using `row_number()` should work too.

Answer (score 2):

> I would like to retrieve one large table of products with the latest rows from all the joined tables

I think that you want equality conditions with correlated subqueries in the `where` clause rather than `in` conditions with aggregate queries. This lets you filter each joined table with the "latest" record for the given `productToken`.

```
SELECT *
FROM products p
JOIN productsStore  psr ON psr.productToken = p.productToken
JOIN productsStatus psu ON psu.productToken = p.productToken
JOIN productsPrice  ppr ON ppr.produstToken = p.productToken
JOIN categories     c   ON c.categoryToken  = p.categoryToken
WHERE 
    p.shopToken = '$shopToken' 
    AND p.productID         = (SELECT MAX(p1.productID)         FROM products      p1   WHERE p1.productToken   = p.productToken)
    AND psr.productStoreID  = (SELECT MAX(psr1.productStoreID)  FROM productsStore psr1 WHERE psr1.productToken = p.productToken)
    AND psu.productStatusID = (SELECT MAX(psu1.productStatusID) FROM productStatus psu1 WHERE psu1.productToken = p.productToken)
    AND ppr.productPriceID  = (SELECT MAX(ppr1.productPriceID)  FROM productsPrice ppr1 WHERE ppr1.productToken = p.productToken)
    AND c.categoryID        = (SELECT MAX(c1.categoryID)        FROM category      c1   WHERE c1.productToken   = p.productToken)
```

If you are running MySQL 8.0 (or MariaDB 10.3 or higher), you can use `ROW_NUMBER()` in subqueries instead:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT p.*, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY productToken ORDER BY productID DESC) rn
    FROM products p
) p
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT psr.*, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY productToken ORDER BY productStoreID DESC) rn
    FROM productsStore psr
) psr ON psr.productToken = p.productToken AND psr.rn = 1
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT psu.*, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY productToken ORDER BY productStatusID DESC) rn
    FROM productsStatus psu
) psu ON psu.productToken = p.productToken AND psu.rn = 1
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT ppr.*, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY productToken ORDER BY productsPriceID DESC) rn
    FROM productsPrice ppr
) ppr ON ppr.productToken = p.productToken AND ppr.rn = 1
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT c.*, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY productToken ORDER BY categoryID DESC) rn
    FROM categories c
) c ON c.productToken = p.productToken AND c.rn = 1
WHERE p.shopToken = '$shopToken' AND p.rn = 1
```

Comment: thank you a lot, but it did not solve my problem - still empty result, and one more question did you use any generator to generate your code ? - looks nice and clean

Comment: @Rudi: if you run the first query with just this in the `WHERE` clause (nothing else) do you get some rows back or not? `WHERE 
    p.shopToken = '$shopToken'`

Comment: yes, SELECT * FROM products p WHERE p.shopToken = '$shopToken', is working correctly

Comment: @Rudi: no, I mean with all the joins but with that simplified `WHERE` clause.

Comment: oh, yes, I see .. now I've tested the simplified version and yes it retrieved all joined rows

Comment: I found out that the query is correct but retrieves empty result after "updating" (adding a new record to any of the tables), so the issue probably in the logic